# How to add an id to the script using Zend appendScript helper?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to append a script with an id to the page. The example from [Zend's documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html) seems to have a syntax error (line 5):

```
$template = '<div class="book">{{:title}}</div>';
$this->headScript()->appendScript(
    $template,
    'text/x-jquery-tmpl',
    array('id='tmpl-book', 'noescape' => true)
);
```

I've tried `array('id' => 'tmpl-book', 'noescape' => true)`, but this doesn't work: the script is added to the page, but without the id.

Comment: Try my answer, for me it is working since years in many production environments like this. You could also use Ajax (e.g. $.get) to async (or sync) load the templates if needed. Place your templates into seperated js files (e.g. public/js/templates/). Then load them via $.get('/js/templates/test.js',function(template){ //render tpl });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default only `'charset', 'defer', 'language', 'src'` are allowed as on attributes, you need to set `$this->headScript()->setAllowArbitraryAttributes(true);` in order to add any attribute to the script;

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html aboute the middle of the page :

> Note: Arbitrary Attributes are Disabled by Default
>
> By default, HeadScript only will render  attributes that are blessed by
> the W3C. These include 'type', 'charset', 'defer', 'language', and
> 'src'. However, some javascript frameworks, notably » Dojo, utilize
> custom attributes in order to modify behavior. To allow such
> attributes, you can enable them via the setAllowArbitraryAttributes()
> method:
>
> $this->headScript()->setAllowArbitraryAttributes(true);

Answer (score -1):

Use a placeholder isntead!

Read about **Zend Helper Placeholder** here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.view.placeholders.basics.html

I add in my **layout.phtml** just before the closing  tag:

***You can add the line wherever you want in your scripts...***

```
...
<?php echo $this->placeholder('js-templates'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can use the placeholder view helper wherever you want, to add content.

In a **controller action**

**As mentioned in the comments below:**

In my previous version I did forget to stop php syntax and start it again, the commentators are absolutly right, it would not work without it...

Here is the running version: http://ideone.com/hGbtU8

And yes, it is no good practice to insert scripts to the view, but it works.

The best solution would be to create a class that manages insert/update/delete of such templates injected. You could create an abstract class, add templates (or maybe the path to template files) and then output them or add them to your view...

```
...
public function indexAction() {
    ...
    $this->view->placeholder('js-templates')->captureStart(); ?>
    <script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="myId">
        <div class="book">
            {{:title}}
        </div>
    </script>
    <?php $this->view->placeholder('js-templates')->captureEnd();
    ...
}
...
```

Or inside a **view script**

```
    ...
    <?php $this->placeholder('js-templates')->captureStart(); ?>
    <script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="myId">
        <div class="book">
            {{:title}}
        </div>
    </script>
    <?php $this->placeholder('js-templates')->captureEnd(); ?>
    ...
```

Of course, you can also write your own view/layout helper and extend the default placeholder helper.

Hope it helps... Let me know if it doesn't work...

Comment: It will not work because you simply put html into php (action body)

Comment: It will work, you are not putting html to the body, you are putting exactly what is written between captureStart() and captureEnd() to whatever place you echo the content. This will put the <script> tag with the id and type specified into the html body. To use this script template in your page, simply pass the id to your template engine in a document.ready event callback.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to use appendScript, if possible.

Comment: @Scriptlabs: php parser will fail on parsing step, since your `indexAction()` is not valid php.

Comment: @zerkms it will work and php parser will not fail, but generaly its not a good practice to put script and template definition in controller

Comment: @Exlord: could you please show how. php interpreter fails with parse error exactly as I told: http://ideone.com/NrP9ff

Comment: @zerkms ,ok i had not tested this, and was thinking that since captureStart start the output buffering it would work, but i tested and it didn't :D

Comment: @Exlord: you must realize there is parsing and evaluating step. Before script started evaluation it must be syntactically correct.

Comment: I only did forget about the ending and starting of php code ... It will work if you add it. Example: http://ideone.com/hGbtU8